# New puppy​'s​ separation anxiety for previous litter

Tags: dogs, anxiety, dachshunds

We just received a new puppy 6 days ago. She is a dachshund and 13 weeks old.
From the end of the first day (after she realized that her previous litter isn't here) she is very anxious. Eats just a little, doesn't play much, and only wants to sleep in our laps. If we are not having a physical connection with her, she starts whining.

We tried to use her to a crate, but without liking to eat we can't really motivate her. (Of course, we are trying with compliments.)
Also, she received a calming collar. And tried different foods.

I tried to Google this a lot, but no useful advice, as all of the resources are focused on separation anxiety for the current owner. I think she has it for the previous litter.

We will bring her to the vet after the weekend, and also to a trainer in two weeks. (First possible appointments.) But I would like to ask for some advice until then also.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Be patient. It is a child still, suddenly "alone" in a new environment. You may first build trust and relationship (like building a new pack) and then start training. A lots of physical contact is natural in this stage. You can use this too for praising :) Explore together the crate as some kind of cave to hide and build a positive experience with it for your dog.

Comment: Indeed, this was to solution.